# Mac media keys to control last active app

Tags: macos, media-keys

I recently installed a Chrome extension that binds the media keys to web-based media players. It has an option to only control the last active eligible tab, rather than sending the command to every tab with a media player. Made me think, why can't I have this behaviour globally?

So my question is: **Is there a way, using system options, scripts, or third party software, to have the following behaviour?**

**Ideally: Media keys affect only the last app in which some media control was touched.** eg. I'm listening to Soundcloud in Chrome. I press media key `play/pause` and it pauses. I switch to Spotify, but just to browse. I press `play/pause` and Soundcloud starts playing again. But if I pause that again and click the play button in Spotify, then the media keys start controlling that instead of Soundcloud, even if I go back to my Soundcloud tab (without touching its media controls).

However, perhaps the OS won't know when I've touched media controls within an app, in which case a weaker version could be:

**Alternatively: Media keys control last focused app that has media controls.** eg. In the previous scenario, I go to Spotify, media keys bind to that. Now if I go back to Chrome, as long as I don't focus my Soundcloud tab, media keys continue to control Spotify.

Note: I'm on Yosemite currently (and I've seen the big High Sierra media keys gaffe). Solutions for Yosemite would be welcome; ones that work generally, moreso.